# Click on checkbox and go to url with saved data

Tags: javascript

I have filters on my page. I need do, when people click on checkbox, redirect on page with get param `?attr=id-with-comma`, example: `?attr=1,2,3,4`. Where `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` - value of checked checkbox. I have code:

```
function checkFunc() { // this function call when checkbox is clicked
        var id = $("[name=attr]:checked").map(function () {
                      return this.value;
                 }).get().join(",");

         window.location.href = '?attr=' + id;
      }
```

I use GET.

How save data from address bar, when page reloading and write filters? Now I rewrite `attr=..`.

Comment: Just a heads-up, but "clicking a checkbox" and "redirecting" are not generally considered to be actions that make sense happening together.

Comment: Have you tried using a `GET` method to fetch your data? When you parse data through the URL, it's called a `GET` method. You want to retrieve your data like so: `$myData=$_GET['attr'];`

Comment: filters are being run on server or client side?

Comment: why not use links?